# How can i make same height to Div no matter how long the image and text are?

Tags: html, css

here is html code :
i wanna keep the div same height even the size of the pics are long or text is long .. is there a solution for it in css ??
here is a link to code: https://jsfiddle.net/Youssef_X/81drbgz3/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--=============PRODUCTE ITEMS START HERE=======-->
  <section>
    <div class="container product-lists">
      <!-- ====== FIRST ROW HERE ===== -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/game1.jpg" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted.
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">See more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/game2.png" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
             when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">see more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/machine3.png" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description"> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">see morer</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ======= END FIRST ROW ====== -->
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CSS Flexbox (align-items). ( https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ )
I think that could solver your issue?

I see you are using Bootstrap, looks like this may be your solution:
http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/
Basicly adding the .row-eq-height class.

```
<body>
  <!--=============PRODUCTE ITEMS START HERE=======-->
  <section>
    <div class="container product-lists">
      <!-- ====== FIRST ROW HERE ===== -->
      <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/game1.jpg" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted.
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">See more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/game2.png" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
             when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">see more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/machine3.png" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description"> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">see morer</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ======= END FIRST ROW ====== -->
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try a pure flex box solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Bro as u are using BS-4 this works on flex box properties and all the cols inside rows automatically get same height.
I think u have a working code 
But i have added some colors to make it more clear

Note:- If u want all the conetents center aligned just add "align-items-center" class on row

```css
.container.product-lists > .row{background-color:grey} 
.container.product-lists > .row .col-md-4{border:1px solid #dddddd}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--=============PRODUCTE ITEMS START HERE=======-->
  <section>
    <div class="container product-lists">
      <!-- ====== FIRST ROW HERE ===== -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/game1.jpg" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted.
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">See more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/game2.png" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
             when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">see more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="product-list">
            <img src="assets/img/machine3.png" alt="Planet gaming products" />
            <h3 class="title">Eurocoin Interactive</h3>
            <p class="description"> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
            </p><a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">see morer</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ======= END FIRST ROW ====== -->
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes great way to show the cols and rows very clearly ...but no way to solve this issue using bootstrap4  ??

Comment: You just want col height equal  for any amount of content @youssefkhoukhou right?

Comment: Yes exactly , no matter what is the form of the image and no matter now many lines of text are there, ..just to keep the Columns same height

Comment: Just the buttons stick in the bottom please, it will great @Vikas Patel

Comment: .product-list {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
}
.description {
 flex-grow: 1;
}

Add this

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mxs3ma , as you see here , i applied the code but height , doesnt get effected ...https://jsfiddle.net/Youssef_X/81drbgz3/2/

Comment: It will work till 768px viewport below that it will create problem
for that u can add min height on cols using media query @youssefkhoukhou